# Why is the sweetnes of a wine with little sugar called 'trocken'?

Tags: meaning, etymology

I don't have a good explanation for why in Germany a wine with little sugar is called 'trocken'. Does someone know where this comes from? Because the meaning of 'trocken' in Germany is 'such that there is no water'. I'm really wondering ...

Comment: I think this question applies not only to the German language, but to any language. Basically, the question is: Why are wines with little sugar called "dry"? This does not seem to be a question about the German language.

Comment: [Here's a list of 30 countries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweetness_of_wine) where it is just the same.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question seems to require expertise in oenology, not in German language.

Comment: Agree this question, unfortunately, doesn't fit here. Here you might find some good hints (maybe the best you can get): http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview?id=709617

Comment: The question **may** be on-topic on [cooking.se] or [alcohol.se].